# getQuery() returns only one value

Tags: checkboxes, querystring

I have a URL passing values from form checkboxes to a template. All the checkboxes are grouped with the same `name=` attribute. When multiple checkboxes are selected, the query string looks something like:

`?checkValue=12345&checkValue=23456&checkValue=34567`

However, `craft.request.getQuery('checkValue')` returns only the last value (34567 in this case).

How can I retrieve all the values so they can be used and manipulated?

EDIT: I've corrected the naming of the checkboxes from `name="checkValue"` to `name="checkValue[]"`, so now my query string looks like this:

`?checkValue%5B%5D=12345&checkValue%5B%5D=23456&checkValue%5B%5D=34567`

Does that change what can be accessed using `craft.request.getQuery('checkValue')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is not really Craft related. Since you just don't send a valid request. You can't send one key multiple times unless you do it in an array.

The php `$_GET` is a simple array with all your values and you overwrite them again and again.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098397/how-to-pass-an-array-in-get-in-php

Comment: Please see edits to original post.

Answer (score 2):

Using the corrected checkbox name `name=checkValue[]` the submitted values

`?checkValue%5B%5D=12345&checkValue%5B%5D=23456&checkValue%5B%5D=34567`

are converted to an array. The array values can now be accessed using

```
{% set checkVals = craft.request.getQuery('checkValue') %}

{{ checkVals[1] }} {# outputs 23456 #}
```

or

```
{% for cVal in checkVals %}
    {{ cVal }}
{% endfor %}
```